# Magento 2 - How to re-add footer on checkout page after it's removed by default before

Tags: magento2, checkout, layout

I'm trying to re-add footer on checkout page after it's has been removed from Magento 2 Blank Theme:

**magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

I'm tried to overide on my theme:
**Mystore/mytheme/Magento_Checkout/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="false"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

But it didn't working, anyone can help?

Answer (score 7):

Previous solution didn't work for me, so I found another.

In Magento 2 checkout page uses custom layout, placed in 
**vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/page_layout/checkout.xml**

So, you need to replace it with any other layout (for example, to 1column).

Go to **vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout** and copy the file **checkout_index_index.xml** to your theme (without the declarations inside the `<body>`).

Then change this line:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="checkout" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

to

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
```

Then remove the header in the regular way.

Answer (score 4):

I also faced the same issue and it was solved by overriding the default folder.

By default it is disabled in luma/blank theme. you just need to create basic structure on your theme folder and re-add the blocks you want

```
yourthemename\Magento_Checkout\layout\override\theme\Magento\blank
```

just copy checkout_index_index.xml here and in this file paste the below code

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
  <!-- <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="true"/>-->
   <!--<referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true"/>-->
    <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true"/>
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
   <!--<referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/>-->
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need override core layout for this. See [documentation for this](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/layout-override.html)

Create file
*Mystore/mytheme/Magento_Checkout/layout/**override**/checkout_index_index.xml*
with content  like

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="true"/>
        <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="true"/>
        <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true"/>
        <!-- <referenceContainer name="footer-container" remove="true"/> disable remove -->
    </body>
</page>
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to **Magento_Checkout/page_layout** open **checkout.xml**

Add your Block container Header and footer.

Answer (score -1):

Please refer the following thread for your answer

https://community.magento.com/t5/Can-Magento-do/Magento-2-How-to-re-add-footer-on-checkout-page-after-it-s/m-p/30716/highlight/false#M1695

Answer (score -1):

First go to Magento_Checkout in your theme folder
**app/design/frontend/package_name/theme_name/Magento_Checkout**

Now create below folder structure in layout folder on above path.
**override/theme/Magento/blank/checkout_index_index.xml**

in this checkout_index_index.xml file add below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <referenceBlock name="minicart" remove="false" />
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="top.search" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.compare.link" remove="false" />
    <referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="false"/>
    <referenceContainer name="footer-container"  remove="false"/>
</body>
```